# Can't concatenate react table row

Tags: reactjs, object, html-table

I'm trying to outout a table with react, and this code is working fine

```
function RankingTableBody(props) {
    let tableBody;

    if(props.source === 'visitor') {
        tableBody =  TableRowMap(props, props.data.vv_highest, 'highest_' + uuidv4(), 'block');

        return tableBody;
    }
}

function TableRowMap(props, data, tbodyId, show) {
    return (
        <tbody id={tbodyId} style={{display: show}}>
        {data.map(post => (
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Hello World
                </td>
            </tr>
        ))}
        </tbody>
    )
}
```

Since I need 2 `<tbody>` tags, I called twice the function TableRowMap:

```
tableBody =  TableRowMap(props, props.data.vv_highest, 'highest_' + uuidv4(), 'block');
tableBody += TableRowMap(props, props.data.vv_most, 'most_' + uuidv4(), 'block');

return tableBody;
```

But, if I try to console.log `tableBody`, I've `[object Object][object Object]`

How is possible to concatenate the TableRowMap answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
const tableBody = (
<>
{TableRowMap(props, props.data.vv_highest, 'highest_' + uuidv4(), 'block')}
{TableRowMap(props, props.data.vv_most, 'most_' + uuidv4(), 'block')}
</>
)
```